# Laravel multi authorization system

Tags: laravel

I am working for a project, that I need two auth ways.
I have users that will login with username and password, and users with TOKEN.

For now, I am using jwt-auth for users with login / pass

But I can't understand how can I seperate users with TOKEN login.

I have this code at config/auth.php

```
return [
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' =>  App\Models\User::class
    ]
]
];
```

I am trying to use both authentications.

For example, with JWT I login as admin with username/password, get a TOKEN from JWT that expires on 1 hour, and I make requests with that token.

But I have customers running an API that having an standard 64 characters length token, without username/passord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create another auth guard for token auth:

```
'guards' => [
  'api' => [
    'driver' => 'jwt',
    'provider' => 'users',
  ],
  'api_token' => [
    'driver' => 'XXX',
    'provider' => 'users',
  ]
```

XXX - a driver for your token authorisation - maybe 'sanctum', maybe standard 'token' - what you use for "standard 64 characters length token"

Than, use middleware with multiple guards (or with one):

```
Route::get(...)->middleware('auth:api,api_token');
```